# Read in an int in c and ignore anything else

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to read in an int using `scanf()` in order to use for later calculations but I am trying to get it to discard anything after the int.

Essentially I want to be able to prompt the user to answer a question such as

What is 3 + 5?

and for the user to be able to enter either 8 or 8 dog or anything of that nature and it be treated the same. I have tried using `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");` however this causes issues elsewhere in the program by causing other prompts
to not display correctly. I should also that the value read in (the 8 in this case) is needed for other calculations and I need to have the dog portion removed as it causes issues later on in the program as well.

Sample Code to clarify issue in comments

```
printf("What is %d %c %d ", a, oper, b);
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
errno = 0;
num = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
if (num == answer)
    {
    printf("Correct!");
    right++;
    }
else
    {
    printf("Wrong!");
    }
printf("\n");

    if (errno != 0)
{
    printf("Invalid input, it must be just a number \n");
}
```

basically this part grades a math question the user entered

Comment: If you want to ignore anything that follows, just `scanf("%d", &my_int)` exactly once.

Comment: Why use `scanf()` when using `fgets()` is so much better?

Comment: The problem with using it only once is that the dog or whatever garbage that is after the int still remains in stdin and screws up the next prompt for information

Comment: @tacoofdoomk: As you wanted to "ignore anything else", you apparently are not interested int eh rest anyway. And if your file closes, `stdin` is cleared automatically. Problem solved.

Comment: as a sidenote it is easier to limit the users possibility to enter values than having to parse the input i.e. instead reading char by char with fgetc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scanf` can be tricky when trying to read input in this manner.  I'd recommend reading in a whole line using `fgets` then using `strtol` to convert the result to a number.

```
char line[100];
long int num;
fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
errno = 0;
num = strtol(line, NULL, 10);
if (errno != 0) {
    printf("%s is not a number!\n", line);
}
```

EDIT:

What you have looks good, although as chux pointed out in the comments, it isn't detecting a non-numerical value correctly.

This should do it:

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, answer, right;;
    char oper, *p;
    char line[100];
    long int num;

    right=0;
    a=3, b=5, oper='+', answer=8;
    printf("What is %d %c %d ", a, oper, b);
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    errno = 0;
    num = strtol(line, &p, 10);    // p will point to the first invalid character
    if (num == answer)
    {
        printf("Correct!");
        right++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong!");
    }
    printf("\n");

    if (errno != 0 || p == line)
    {
        printf("Invalid input, it must be just a number \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pedantic note: There are 4 tests that can follow `strtol(line,&endptr,10)` to read an `int`: `if (errno)` to detect overflow,  `if num< INT_MIN ||& num > INT_MAX` to detect `int` overflow, `if (line == endptr)` to detect no conversion, `if (*endptr)` to detect trailing garbage (not needed per OP)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, when I ever I try to use the variable I get later it doesn't work the way the variable I obtained with scanf. I need to be able to use the num value for other calculations

Comment: @tacoofdoomk Can you post some sample code that illustrates the issue?

Comment: added some sample code to hopefully help with the issue

Comment: Okay so I got the sample code working however it seems like if I am reading in the values of a, b and oper then I always get wrong without a chance to enter the answer value. My apologies for not mentioning this earlier, I was unaware it would be relevant.

Comment: @tacoofdoomk That's why it's important to post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).